# How to fix the height of a responsive web page using vh and vw

Tags: html, css

I'm new to responsive development and dunno how to look this over the internet.

I have three div containers

```
<div className={styles.mainContainer}>
  <div className={styles.blackContainer}>
    ... Black background
  </div>
  <div className={styles.greyContainer}>
    ... Grey background
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the CSS:

```
.mainContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.blackContainer {
  width: 55vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.greyContainer {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .mainContainer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .blackContainer {
    height: 26.5vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .grayContainer {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  }

}
```

[Image in Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LRTu.png)

[Image in Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgWbn.png)

I can see a preview as I'm using NextJS. In desktop is okay, but when I open it in a Chrome mobile browser, whether it is an iPad or a phone, I can scroll down, how can I avoid scrolling down? In the width and height in my inspect elements from Chrome, the size of the mainContainer is the same as in the screen. (i.e. if I'm in iPhone X, the size of mainContainer is 375 x 812

Answer (score -1):

You can block scrolling down with adding `overflow-y: hidden` into body
look at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: It seems to work for the Firefox Browser, do you have any idea why isn't it working in Chrome?